# How to get rid of the BeautifulSoup html parser error when I'm not using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm going to be making a dictionary program with a GUI but I fell at the first hurdle. I just installed a module ([PyDictionary](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDictionary/1.3.4)) but when I run the following code I get an error.

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary = PyDictionary()
print(dictionary.meaning("fish"))
```

Which returns

```
The code that caused this warning is on line 3 of the file Dictionary.py. To 
get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))
{'Noun': ['any of various mostly cold-blooded aquatic vertebrates usually having scales and breathing through gills', 'the flesh of fish used as food', '(astrology', 'the twelfth sign of the zodiac; the sun is in this sign from about February 19 to March 20'], 'Verb': ['seek indirectly', 'catch or try to catch fish or shellfish']}
```

Comment: PyDictionary uses BeautifulSoup, so by using PyDictionary, you are actually using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: It seems PyDictionary is obsolete, since it makes use of a web request, and uses an old HTML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a problem with PyDictionary, as noted [here](https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary/issues/1). The reason it is throwing a BeautifulSoup error is because PyDictionary is implemented using BeautifulSoup.

It looks like the issue may have been fixed, however. Did you install PyDictionary with pip? If so, try installing directly from the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary).

Edit: I tested using the repo to install and the issue was resolved. I would advise you to do the same. If you're not sure how to do this feel free to ask.